# Appending location.href to a form within an iframe

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

Here is what i got:

1=page containing a form
2=page containing an iframe of 1

I created an invisible textarea in a form, so it could be filled with URL of page that cointains an iframe.

Both 1 and 2 are on different domains. I got full access to both sites.

What im trying to do is to know where from was the form sent.

Not sure if im clear enough:

[image: iframe]

I already tried to append:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('textarea#id_subject').append(window.parent.location.href)
            });
            </script>
```

to 1, but it didnt work. How could i achieve this, any idea?

BTW, this iframe is going to be attached to 10-100 other sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add url of parent window as GET parameter in iframe url:

```
This goes in parent page.
<iframe src="http://something.com/form.html?parent_url={your url goes here}">
</iframe>
```

It can be done both on server side or on client side. From inside of iframe you can access this value on server side (by reading GET parameter), or on client side (by reading `location.href`).

Comment: damnit... I removed ".parent" from my code and everything works :) thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

> this iframe is going to be attached to 10-100 other sites

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is going to get in your way.

Pass the URL via some other technique. A query string in the `src` of the iframe is a reasonable bet.

Comment: both you and Riateche were right, the reason it didnt work for me is because i called window.parent.location.href in the iframe instead of window.location.href :) thanks!